# My express router not working on my express app

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I am learning express js.
Here I am creating a crud project in student data. I have created routes and controllers but when I include it in my main app.js , my router seems not working.
Please guide me.
P.S:I am working on ES6.
My app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import connectDB from './db/connectdb.js'
import web from "./routes/web.js"
import{join} from 'path'
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || "8080"
const DATABASE_URL ="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"

//loading static files
app.use('/student',express.static(join(process.cwd(),"public")))

//loading routes
app.get('/student',web)



//set template engine
app.set("view engine","ejs")



app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Server listening at port no:"+port)
})
connectDB(DATABASE_URL)
```

My router file saved as web.js

```
import express from 'express';
import StudentController from "../controllers/studentController.js"
const router = express.Router();

router.route('/',StudentController.getAllDoc)



export default router
```

My studentController.js

```
class StudentController{
    
  static getAllDoc = (req,res)=>{
    res.render('index')
    }

}
export default StudentController
```

I expected my ejs file named as index.ejs to run which is in views folder, but the result is like cannot get /student/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.use` is used to register middleware, serve group of route,...
- `.get`, `.post` is a single route.

Please change your code to something like this:

app.js

```
//loading static files
app.use(express.static(join(process.cwd(),"public")))

//loading routes
app.use('/student',web)
```

web.js

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',StudentController.getAllDoc)

export default router
```